# How to implement PartialEq on Vector for my own structs?

Tags: rust, traits

I have the following definition:

```
pub struct List<T> {
    memory:  Vec<T>,
}
```

I would get the equivalent of `#[derive(PartialEq)]` for this type like describe in [How can I implement PartialEq?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#how-can-i-implement-partialeq)

I use a match expression, like:

```
impl<T: PartialEq> PartialEq for List<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &List<T>) -> bool {
        self.memory == other.memory      
    }
}
impl<T: fmt::Debug> fmt::Debug for List<T> where T:Display {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        try!(write!(f, "["));
        for (count, v) in self.memory.iter().enumerate() {
            if count != 0 { try!(write!(f, ", ")); }
            try!(write!(f, "{}", v));
        }
        write!(f, "]")
    }
}
impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        List {
            memory: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
    // push() add to end of list
    pub fn push(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.memory.push(value);
    }
}
```

But the compiler gives me these errors:

> error: mismatched types [E0308]
>
> if ! ( * left_val == * right_val ) {
>
> note: in this expansion of assert_eq!
>
> help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
>
> note: expected type `librusty_data_structures::List<u32>`
>
> note:    found type `[_; 4]`

main.rs that produce compile errors

```
let mut listex: List<u32> = List::new();
listex.push(17);
listex.push(18);
listex.push(19);
listex.push(20);            
assert_eq!(listex, [17, 18, 19, 20]);
```

I don't understand why that matters. Why is it even looking at that type?

Comment: That code compiles for me. Can you post the complete file which throws that error?

Comment: updated with main.rs throws that error.

Comment: Do you want `List<T>` to comparable to `[T; 4]` as well? (Note that you implemented `PartialEq<Rhs = List<u32>>` for `List<u32>` so you can only compare `List<u32>` with `List<u32>`.)

Comment: I'm new to Rust, what do you mean by `PartialEq<Rhs = List<u32>>`?

Comment: `PartialEq` can be implemented for different Lhs (the thing on the left of `==`) and Rhs (the thing on the right of `==`), and if you don't specify `Rhs`, it defaults to `Self`. So with your current implementation, you can only compare `List<T>` with `List<T>` while that `assert_eq!` tries to compare `List<u32>` with `[u32; 4]`.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how does `Vec<T>` implement `PartialEq`


    let mut v = Vec::new();
    v.push(1);
    v.push(2);
    v.push(3);
println!("{}", v == [1, 2, 3]);

Answer (score 3):

`listex` and `[17, 18, 19, 20]` have different types (`List<u32>` and `[_; 4]`) , so you cannot check for their equality. You need to change the type of one of the arguments of `assert_eq!()` so the types match. The simplest option would be to reference `listex`'s `memory`:

`assert_eq!(&listex.memory[0..4], [17, 18, 19, 20]);`

Or you can convert `[17, 18, 19, 20]` to a `List<u32>` so that the `PartialEq` implementation for `List<T>` can be put into action.

If you were to compare `listex` with another `List<32>`, your `PartialEq` implementation would allow checks for equality (though you would need the `List<T>` to derive `Debug` in order to do perform `assert_eq!()` on them).

**Edit**: as for your question "Why is it even looking at that type?", notice that in your implementation of `PartialEq`:

`fn eq(&self, other: &List<T>)`

You specify that `eq` works only for two arguments of type `&List<T>` (`&self` points to `List<T>`).

Comment: For the purpose of this example a simple `#[derive(Debug)]` would suffice :).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution, following [cuviper response](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-implement-partialeq-for-my-own-structs/7122/2?u=lemoussel) on The Rust Programming Language Forum

```
impl<T, U> PartialEq<U> for List<T>
    where Vec<T>: PartialEq<U>
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &U) -> bool {
        self.memory.eq(other)
    }
}
```

To test :

```
let mut listex: List<u32> = List::new();

listex.push(17);
listex.push(18);
listex.push(19);
listex.push(20);            

println!("{}", listex == [17, 18, 19, 20]);
```